# Jscript try & catch get error message

Tags: try-catch, jscript

As the title says im trying to get a error exception :

```
try{
objshell.run("testfile.exe");
}catch(ex){
WScript.echo(ex.message);
}
```

the code above just returns an empty message box if file testfile.exe does not exist.

is there any way to read the error reason? (example : file does not exists)

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between JScript and JScript .NET. If you are using Microsoft's implementation, then you could additionally print out ex.description, ex.name and ex.number.

In your code, just use: 
`WScript.echo(ex);`